# Complete words from partial substrings in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

How can I achieve fish-like path completion in zsh?

Suppose I have a file named `abce-fg`, in fish shell when I type:

```
$ ls abef<Press Tab here>
```

fish will complete `abce-fg` for me.

Notice that `abef` is a subsequence of **ab**c**e**-**f**g.

How do I achieve this in zsh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:|?=**'
```

---

Alternatively, install the [`zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) for fuzzy matching, spelling correction, real-time autocompletion and many more completion features.

[image: live file search]

[image: live history search]

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Marlon . But I still have a small problem. When preceded with a directory, instead of listing all candidates, zsh will simply complete the common prefix. Say I have `abcde` and `bcde` in `/tmp/`, when I type `/tmp/cde<Tab>` zsh will complete the common prefix, which is a empty string in the case of `abcde` and `bcde`. Is it possible to list the candidates when preceded with directory?